# Vectors as functions and finding a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The cosine space $$F_3$$ contains all the combinations of

$$
y(x)=A\cos x+B\cos(2x)+C\cos(3x).
$$
Find a basis for the subspace that

$$y(0)=0$$

So what I thought was since y(0)=0 for no matter what, since cos0=cos0
I thought the bases would be $A\cos x$.

but the question says that the answer is

$$
\cos x-\cos(2x) \mbox{ and}\\
\cos x-\cos(3x).
$$

How come? I didn't understand this whole concept of a vectors as functions anyway. What is meant here can someone help me out please?

Comment: $y(0)=0$ if and only if $A+B+C=0$. You want to find functions such that any other $y(x)$ such that $A+B+C=0$ can be written as a linear combination of them. To make it easier you can think of this as just vectors (not functions) so the question becomes: Find a basis for the subspace of $K^3$ of vectors $(A,B,C)$ such that $A+B+C=0$.

Answer (score 1):

For all $y=f(x)$ satisfying $f(0) = 0$ can be written as $f(x) = \lambda (\cos x-\cos(2x))  +\mu (\cos x-\cos(3x)) $.

This holds because $A+B+C =0$, there is three elements, when two elements are valued, the other are valued.

The basis can be any other type: $ \{(\cos(2x)-\cos(3x)) , (\cos x-\cos(2x)) \}$ so answer is not unique.

If $\cos(x)$ is a basis, that's wrong because $f(x) = \cos(x)$, then $f(0) = \cos(0) = 1$.